# Problem Replacing <br> Tags with Newline Using bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup

**Problem:** I cannot replace `<br>` tags with a newline character using Beautiful Soup 4.

**Code:** My program (the relevant portion of it) currently looks like

```
for br in board.select('br'):
    br.replace_with('\n')
```

but I have also tried `board.find_all()` in place of `board.select()`.

**Results:** When I use `board.replace_with('\n')` all `<br>` tags are replaced with the string literal `\n`. For example, `<p>Hello<br>world</p>` would end up becoming `Hello\nworld`. Using `board.replace_with(\n)` causes the error

```
File "<ipython-input-27-cdfade950fdf>", line 10
    br.replace_with(\n)
                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

**Other Information:** I am using a Jupyter Notebook, if that is of any relevance. Here is my full program, as there may be some issue elsewhere that I have overlooked.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://boards.4chan.org/g/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
board = soup.find('div', class_='board')

for br in board.select('br'):
    br.replace_with('\n')

message = [obj.get_text() for obj in board.select('.opContainer .postMessage')]
image = [obj['href'] for obj in board.select('.opContainer .fileThumb')]
pid = [obj.get_text() for obj in board.select('.opContainer .postInfo .postNum a[title="Reply to this post"]')]
time = [obj.get_text() for obj in board.select('.opContainer .postInfo .dateTime')]

for x in range(len(image)):
    image[x] = "https:" + image[x]

post = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": pid,
    "Time": time,
    "Image": image,
    "Message": message,
    })
post

pd.options.display.max_rows
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

display(post)
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried and it works for me, my bs4 version is 4.8.0, and I am using Python 3.5.3, 
example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('hello<br>world')

for br in soup('br'):
    br.replace_with('\n')

# <br> was replaced with \n successfully
assert str(soup) == '<html><body><p>hello\nworld</p></body></html>'

# get_text() also works as expected
assert soup.get_text() == 'hello\nworld' 

# it is a \n not a \\n 
assert soup.get_text() != 'hello\\nworld'
```

I am not used to work with Jupyter Notebook, but seems that your problem is that whatever you are using to visualize the data is showing you the string representation instead of actually printing the string,
hope this helps,
Regards,
adb

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing after converting to soup, try replacing the `<br>` tags before converting. Like,

`soup = BeautifulSoup(str(page.content).replace('<br>', '\n'), 'html.parser')`

Hope this helps! Cheers!

P.S.: I did not get any logical reason why this is not working after changing into soup.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with variations of

```
page = requests.get("https://boards.4chan.org/g/")
str_page = page.content.decode()
str_split = '\n<'.join(str_page.split('<'))
str_split = '>\n'.join(str_split.split('>'))
str_split = str_split.replace('\n', '')
str_split = str_split.replace('<br>', ' ')
soup = BeautifulSoup(str_split.encode(), 'html.parser')
```

for the better part of two hours, I have determined that the Panda data-frame prints the newline character as a string literal. Everything else indicates that the program is working as intended, so I assume this has been the problem all along.

Answer (score -1):

for some reason direct replace with newline does not work with bs4 you have to first replace with some other unique character (character sequence preferably) and then replace that sequence in text with newline.

try this.

```
for br in soup.find_all('br'): br.replace_with('+++')
text=soup.get_text().replace('+++','\n)
```